# How can I install Ubuntu on a MacBook 6.1?

Tags: partitioning, macbook-pro, livedvd, bootcamp

I would like to install Ubuntu on a MacBook 6.1 (MAC OSX 10.6.8), but I don't understand how to do so ... Boot Camp (v3.0.4) gives me a message «impossible de continuer le téléchargement. Le logiciel d'assistance Windows n'est pas disponible.»

some hours later :
I've success to start with a live-dvd !
So, I gave up with Boot Camp.

The problem, Actually, is "how to resize the Mas's partition ?"
When I try to do this, the  Sisk Utility says me the operation can't be accomplished because there are errors on the partition.. I've to repair those but I don't know how to process without the Installation dvd of Mac OSX....

Sorry for this bad english, tell me for precisions if you need to !

Answer (score 1):

Solution :

- Start computer with an Ubuntu LiveCD (cmd + S at starting)
- open Gparted, and resize the partitions as required
- restart computer with mac
- install rEFIt
- restart again with "C"
- Install Ubuntu :)